# What input is the API expecting?

Tags: api

I need to use this API : https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api/ 
and i want to know how can i know the input is this API expecting.

Comment: Read their docs or read the error messages returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api you need to request to is

```
http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/
```

If you want to do a full text search you have to pass in a `q` request param in the url like

```
http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=YOUR_TEXT
```

If you want to limit the response from the api call to 10 records, you can use `limit` param

```
http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=YOUR_TEXT&limit=10
```

Go through the [documents](https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api/) to see a complete list of input params that can be passed in the api call.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Postman in order to run or test api.